# keybd_event() how to find bScan code

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a little understanding problem with the 2nd parameter (bScan).

My goal is to find the right bScan code for each button.

```
   VOID WINAPI keybd_event(
  _In_ BYTE      bVk,
  _In_ BYTE      bScan,
  _In_ DWORD     dwFlags,
  _In_ ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo
);
```

[keybd_event function Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx)

I have read that the button for the key 5 have bScancode - Hex number: 0x86. But I would be very interested in how to find the bScan code.

```
KeyCode = '5' 
keybd_event(VkKeyScan(KeyCode), 0x86, 0, 0); // ‘5’ Press
keybd_event(VkKeyScan(KeyCode), 0x86, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // ‘5’ Release
```

The function MapVirtualKey () has looked interesting, but unfortunately I get an output of 5. I think so I misunderstood something. Would someone enlighten me? Thank you very much.

```
UINT scanCode = MapVirtualKey('5', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
```

Comment: Did you miss the big "deprecated" warning at the top of the documentation? Scan codes can be [easily looked up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: hi Cody Gray, thanks for your answer. You have right i miss the "deprecated" warning :D So i think i use SendInput. Still to the understanding. Is there no possibility to request this bScancode? So I would have to create a separate list with all bScancodes, do I see the correct?

Comment: You don't need to deal with scan codes at all, just use virtual key codes instead and let the OS translate them for you. Or, in the case of `SendInput()`, you can even use actual Unicode text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scan code depends on your hardware. `5` / `%` is usually 0x06 and `MapVirtualKey('5', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC)` does indeed return 0x06 on my machine.

The top bit (0x80) is set when the key is released so the scan code for `5` key down is 0x06 and 0x86 for key up.